# jqueryui droppable stop event is not being fired

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I don't understand why `nextPlayer` isn't being called when I drop the first game piece:

```js
window.turn = 0

function init_draggable() {
    var params = {}
    params.revert = 'invalid'
    $('#player0').draggable(params)
}
init_draggable()

function init_droppable() {
    var params = {}
    params.stop = nextPlayer
    params.activeClass = 'ui-state-hover'
    $('#square0').droppable(params)
}
init_droppable()

function nextPlayer() {
    alert('Next Player!')
    $('#player' + turn).draggable('destroy')
    $('#square' + turn).droppable('destroy')
    turn = (turn + 1) % 2

    var params = {}
    params.revert = 'invalid'
    $('#player' + turn).draggable(params)

    params = {}
    params.stop = nextPlayer
    params.classes = { 'ui-droppable-active': 'ui-state-hover' }
    $('#square' + turn).droppable(params)
}
```

```css
.player {
    font-size:40px;
    float:left;
}

.square {
    font-size:40px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    width:60px;
}
.ui-draggable {
    cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="player" id="player0">&#9817;</div>
<div class="square" id="square0">&nbsp;</div>
<br clear="left">
<div class="player" id="player1">&#9823;</div>
<div class="square" id="square1">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called `drop`, not `stop`.
Go to bed!